# Struts 1 Ajax call processed twice

Tags: ajax, struts-1

I have a Struts 1 application that uses a little bit a Ajax to create and delete some objects in the application. For both the create and the delete operations, when the operation is posted by the browser it gets processed twice by the server.

This is **not** a case of the ajax being posted twice by the browser. I used a the Paros proxy tool to confirm that the ajax request is sent only once by the browser, but my action class still gets called twice.

Using Eclipse I set a debug breakpoint, and have noticed that the call stack is not the same for each time through my action class.

First pass I get

```
MyActionClass.getDisplayPage(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 65   
MyActionClass(Action).execute(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 224 
ExecuteAction.execute(ActionContext, Action, ActionConfig, ActionForm) line: 53 
ExecuteAction(AbstractExecuteAction).execute(ActionContext) line: 64    
ExecuteAction(ActionCommandBase).execute(Context) line: 48  
ChainBase.execute(Context) line: 190    
LookupCommand.execute(Context) line: 304    
ChainBase.execute(Context) line: 190    
ComposableRequestProcessor.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 280   
ActionServlet.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1858   
ActionServlet.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 459
```

Second pass I get (extra lines marked with `***`)

```
MyActionClass.getDisplayPage(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 65   
***MyActionClass.unspecified(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 199  
***MyActionClass(DispatchAction).dispatchMethod(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, String) line: 242   
***MyActionClass(DispatchAction).execute(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 167  
***MyActionClass(Action).execute(ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 217  
ExecuteAction.execute(ActionContext, Action, ActionConfig, ActionForm) line: 53 
ExecuteAction(AbstractExecuteAction).execute(ActionContext) line: 64    
ExecuteAction(ActionCommandBase).execute(Context) line: 48  
ChainBase.execute(Context) line: 190    
LookupCommand.execute(Context) line: 304    
ChainBase.execute(Context) line: 190    
ComposableRequestProcessor.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 280   
ActionServlet.process(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1858   
ActionServlet.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 459
```

Other than the marked differences, the call stacks are identical.

Here is the struts config action pertaining to this post

```
<action path="/myAjaxRequest"
  type="com..example.MyActionClass"
  name="myActionForm"
  parameter="save">
</action>
```

Does anybody have any ideas what the where the second pass through is coming from? I don't know where to begin to look.

Comment: I'd start by looking at the parameter(s) coming in and the dispatch process. I don't recall the exact request path at the moment, but it seems like a dispatch action should be calling the dispatch method per-request. The second request may be missing the dispatch param (hence "unspecified") but somehow still finds the same method? Not sure--would need to see some configuration.

Comment: My unspecified() method calls the correct method, so that must be why it is finding its way to the right place. It still doesn't explain why to request gets processed twice. I added the struts config for the relevant action. Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: How does `unspecified` know what to call? In any case, if you're *certain* there aren't two requests on the wire, you need to examine the request path through the request processor, and what happens at the return point(s) of the methods called.

Comment: In this particular class there is only one thing to do, so unspecified calls that method.

Comment: I determined that there was only one request being made by passing my browser through a proxy and monitoring the traffic. For each request being passed through the proxy, there were 2 passes through the action class on the server. Unless my proxy is lying to me, I am fairly certain that only one request is being made.

Comment: If there's only one thing to do, why are you using a dispatch action? In any case, the steps are the same--you need to trace through the request processor to find out how it's getting another request to process--it thinks there are two posts. If those aren't on the wire, something is spectacularly wrong. Since most people don't get two request processing cycles per-request, there's something in your config, the response, etc. forcing the second cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this behaviour is caused by a "feature" of the application. Whoever designed the application overrode the DispatchAction.execute() method. The overriding execute() method, when receiving a null ActionForward from an action class, will attempt to call the action again using a different call path.

Since my action is servicing an ajax request, it was returning null on purpose after executing successfully. The result was that my action was being called again by the execute() method, and the request would be processed a second time.